# Bootstrap carousel images disappears to early

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When I slide to a next image, or when the slider/carousel automatically switches to the next image the previous image disapears too fast, which gives it an extremely ugly look. I've made a video to make clear what I mean, can be checked over here.

[Link to video](http://cl.ly/2f231d2K170A)

Anyone has an idea?

Code for the carousel:

```
<div id="contactslidebox" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

```
<div class="item active">
  <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/assets/images/_userfiles/contact/carousel/brussels.jpg" alt="press contact arts square brussels miami hong kong florida usa europe release support">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>ARTS SQUARE</h3>
    <p>Brussels head office</p>
    <a href="#" class="buttonstyle">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/assets/images/_userfiles/contact/carousel/miami.jpg" alt="press contact arts square brussels miami hong kong florida usa europe release support">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>ARTS SQUARE</h3>
    <p>Miami office</p>
    <a href="#" class="buttonstyle">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/assets/images/_userfiles/contact/carousel/press.jpg" alt="press contact arts square brussels miami hong kong florida usa europe release support">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>ARTS SQUARE</h3>
    <p>Press contact</p>
    <a href="#" class="buttonstyle">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/assets/images/_userfiles/contact/carousel/customer-support.jpg" alt="press contact arts square brussels miami hong kong florida usa europe release support">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>ARTS SQUARE</h3>
    <p>Customer support</p>
    <a href="#" class="buttonstyle">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would rather a link to your site or a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Did you try `interval` - `$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 2000})`?

Comment: Website is still in development, I get the fact that a jsfiddle is always nice to have, but I don't have the time atm to make one. I'm on a schedule here. (my apologies). I hope someone ran in the same problem and can help me in such a way.

Comment: @user3388636 interval is for changing the image on a certain time, it's not about that. It's about the fact that my image disapears when the animation happens (as shown in the video).

Comment: I see. Try to play with `emulateTransitionEnd()` in Bootstrap JS.

Comment: How did you make it work ?